# Adding onChange function dynamically while appending

Tags: jquery

i've been asking myself some jquery issues for a while since i fail googleing questions caused by a lack of 'the lingo' maybe. It's about creating an element in jquery dynamically. So i could do it like:

```
placeElement = $('<select/>');

placeElement.on('change', function () { do_sthg(); });
```

I could do it in different ways, just to give an example what i mean.

I created a function a while ago, that add's elements to a page when the user clicks on an edit button, worked fine so far. But as i edited this function later i stumbled upon the fact that i create elements like shown below and now want to add a onChange-Function in that "type of creating an element".

```
$("#edit td."+value).append(
    $("<select/>", {
        'name': value,
        'id':'rankid_select'
    })
);
```

when i add it to the element

```
$("<select/>", {
    'name': value,
    'id':'rankid_select',
    'onchange': function () {
        check_something_that_could_be_wrong();
     }
})
```

the function is called whenever the edit button is clicked, just like an ordinary function but not on changing the select-element. So based on that i have 3 questions:

1. how do i call that different styles i can create elements with in jquery? Like `$('#element').html('...').attr('...').etc('...')...;` 
   or as seen above `$("<select/>", { 'name': value, 'id':'rankid_select' })`.
2. How do i add a function in the shown type of creating an element?
3. Is one of the solutions above 'wrong' or 'dirty' from a pro-programmers view?

thank u so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your question, but I apologize if I'm not quite getting it...

1) The various actions you can do with jQuery are called "methods". The parts inside the parentheses are called "selectors".

jQuery works by passing "selectors" into "methods" that can be chained together. This process makes the selectors the "arguments" to the method. `$("#selector").method("other argument");`

The "$" is a shorthand for the jQuery() method, so even the 1st selector is an argument passed in to create the initial jQuery object.

Each subsequent method on that object returns a value that gets passed in to the next method in the chain, until the final value is placed on the page.

2)  `$("<select/>").on("change", function(){ // do some stuff when the value changes});`

3) Modern best practice for web design is to separate markup/content (HTML) from interactive functionality (JS) or layout/appearance (CSS). In this sense, your very 1st example is the most correct because it keeps things separate.

Your later examples result in "inline" JavaScript becoming part of the HTML markup. This works but is often considered an outdated (and inflexible/difficult to maintain) practice.

The preferred approach is to attach event listeners to objects in the DOM, as shown in #2.

By using `$("#selectedElement").on(...)` you keep the JS in your .js files, which can improve things like code reuse and ease of maintenance.

Instead of having an inline "onClick" function appear in *every* `<select/>` element in the HTML, you can have 1 bit of JS that achieves the same thing, but only needs to be maintained in 1 place.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say either way you have done it is wrong, do what you feel you are comfortable with. Personally, I prefer the syntax like that below (which I hope also solves your problem).

```
var selectBox = $('<select/>')
                    .prop('name', value)
                    .prop('id', 'rankid_select' + $.guid++)
                    .on('change', function () {
                        check_something_that_could_be_wrong();
                });
$(container).append(selectBox);
```

Using a GUID assigns the control a unique number, keeping the control unique. You can omit this if you are wanting the ID to be the same across the board.

Comment: Good to hear, sometimes i'm absolutely unsure bout the syntax i use when directly using stuff i just read about. I'd prefer that solution too. maybe just as i find it more comfortable writing and reading it.

Comment: I prefer the above precisely because it makes it readable. As long as it is easy to read and debug it's good practice. When you minify your scripts for production it is all compressed regardless, so it's good for you and any team members :)